# how to remove sidebar from one page using php and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am writing this code in page.php for remove sidebar in one page

```
<?php if (is_page('x')) : ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

... where "x" is the ID number of that page.

but i am  having a bit of trouble though the forum which is the page in question does not stretch across the whole page.
how can i solve this problem

Comment: Might be you need to take the surrounding related div in the condition too.

Comment: What do you mean by does not stretch across the whole page?

Comment: This is a question for - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: means which ever content i add is display on all page include sidebar space also

Comment: The best thing to use as aparameter is the page slug i.e. if(is_page('PageName'))

Answer (score 0):

That your page does not stretch over the entire width must be a CSS-issue. Try adding following css style to the layer (div) that conatins your content (wich you would like to stretch to the entire width of the parent container:

```
width:100%;
```

For additional help, you should edit your answer and provide a link or even your html composition in plain code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the page width is that it is controlled by CSS from the `<body>` tag. If the sidebar is activated the `<body>` will have: `class="... sidebar..."` and the CSS rule that changes the width is based on `.sidebar .entry` so you have to stop wordpress from adding the sidebar class to `<body>`...